# Visual Studio Test Run: Run Coded UI automated tests from test plans in the Test hub

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, continuous-deployment

**Build Definition**

I am using the same machine as Build and Release configuration. I have created build successfully. Using build I am able to execute Coded UI scripts in **Visual Studio Test Task** in build and they are working fine  My configuration is for build definition is mentioned below

[image]

**Release Destination**

after successful build definition and execution of test scripts, My next plan is to Run Automated Tests from Test plans in the Test Hub. I have associated my test scripts with Test cases also. Please have a look at the image of my release definition where I have selected Test Run using the Test run

[image]

**Notification** I receive after failed execution of automated test from test plan in test hub is

```
Deployment of release Release-11 Rejected in Deploy Test Scripts.
```

**Log**

```
2018-02-21T14:24:20.8978238Z AgentName: EVSRV017-DEVSRV017-4
2018-02-21T14:24:20.8978238Z AgentId: 29
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9038250Z ServiceUrl: https://mytfsserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9038250Z TestPlatformVersion: 
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9038250Z EnvironmentUri: dta://env/Calculator/_apis/release/16/20/1
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9038250Z QueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 3000
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9038250Z MaxQueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 10000
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9048252Z QueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 3000
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9058254Z MaxQueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 50000
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9058254Z RetryCountWhileConnectingToTfs: 3
2018-02-21T14:24:20.9058254Z ===========================================
2018-02-21T14:24:21.3909224Z Initializing the Test Execution Engine
```

**Warning**

```
2018-02-21T14:25:02.1240674Z ##[warning]Failure attempting to call the restapis. Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2018-02-21T14:25:02.1240674Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2018-02-21T14:25:02.1240674Z    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2018-02-21T14:25:02.1240674Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

**ERROR:**

```
2018-02-22T10:10:42.0007605Z ##[error]System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I added debug variable and it seems that when creating a setting file, it is something like system.io exception.

**Enabled DEBUG LOG**

```
2018-02-22T20:17:53.8151287Z Initializing the Test Execution Engine
2018-02-22T20:17:53.8161287Z ##[debug]Creating test settings. test settings name : 44de4d5b-f134-4ba2-b0de-ebd8d30b4d22
2018-02-22T20:18:35.3911287Z ##[warning]Failure attempting to call the restapis. Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2018-02-22T20:18:35.3931287Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Failure attempting to call the restapis. Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

**TFS Agent Log**

```
[INFO VstsAgentWebProxy] No proxy setting found.    
[INFO ConfigurationStore] IsServiceConfigured: False
[INFO ConfigurationManager] Is service configured: False
```

**Worker Log**

```
[2018-02-23 19:32:17Z INFO VstsAgentWebProxy] No proxy setting found.
[2018-02-23 19:32:52Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2018-02-23 19:32:52Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2018-02-23 19:32:53Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobServerQueue] Catch exception during update timeline records, try to update these timeline records next time.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO ProcessInvoker] Finished process with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:49.0055812.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO StepsRunner] Step result: Failed
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO StepsRunner] Update job result with current step result 'Failed'.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO StepsRunner] Current state: job state = 'Failed'
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobRunner] Job result after all job steps finish: Failed
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobRunner] Run all post-job steps.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobRunner] Job result after all post-job steps finish: Failed
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobRunner] Completing the job execution context.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 2 batches web console lines, success rate: 2/2.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobRunner] Shutting down the job server queue.
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z ERR  JobServerQueue] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: String or binary data would be truncated.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.JobServerQueue.<ProcessTimelinesUpdateQueueAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
[2018-02-23 19:33:34Z INFO JobServerQueue] Fire signal to shutdown all queues.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] All queue process task stopped.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] Web console line queue drained.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 2 log files or attachments, success rate: 2/2.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] File upload queue drained.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] Timeline update queue drained.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobServerQueue] All queue process tasks have been stopped, and all queues are drained.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO JobRunner] Raising job completed event.
[2018-02-23 19:33:35Z INFO Worker] Job completed.
```

I will be thankful to you if anyone can identify where I am missing something or what I need to fix this issue so that I can execute automated tests from test plans in the test hub.

Regards

Comment: What's the OS do you use? win server 2008 R2 or 2012 R2 or others? Have you set the proxy for TFS? Have you started the antivirus software? Seems it's connection issue.

Comment: win server 2008 R2. Yes, Proxy for TFS is already set. It is VM with no anti-virus

Comment: To me it seems when it is going to create test setting file, it is getting exception of IOException and because of this issue, TFS is closing connection forcibly. whereas,  i have not added any test setting file. any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Based on your questions, i have reviewed worker and agent logs and my findings are updated in post

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message "`Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`" and your clarification. It should be related to the known issue on win server 2008 R2. Please refer to below article for details:

[Team Foundation Server: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/02/10/team-foundation-server-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/)

> However the bug has been fixed by the Windows team and they have
>   released a QFE for it.  You can find the QFE [**here**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/981898/a-file-does-not-download-from-an-iis-7-5-server-that-is-running-window).  You will
>   need to install it on all of your ATs.

So, just try to install the hotfix and restart the computer after you apply this hotfix, then try it again.

You can also try to use the initial workarounds that list in the blog:

> 1. Open the IIS Manager
> 2. In the Connections pane, make sure the name of your AT is selected.
> 3. In the middle pane (titled “ Home”), make sure you are
>      in the “Features View” (bottom) and scroll down to the Management
>      section.
> 4. Double-click the “Configuration Editor” icon.
> 5. The middle pane should now have the title “Configuration Editor”. 
>      In the Section pull down near the top, expand the
>      system.applicationHost and select “webLimits”.
> 6. You should now see a bunch of property value pairs, one of which is
>      named “minBytesPerSecond”.  Its value is most like 240.  You will
>      want to lower this value for the workaround.

Besides, another possibility is that it's caused by the Proxy server, just try to bypass the proxy server, then check it again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to install QFE. it says "The update is not application to your computer". I have already installed IIS. My application is desktop based application which will execute when i will click on run button in test hub of TFS. In IIs manager, minBytesPerSecond is already set to 240. as for bypass proxy server, I am not on TFS Server. I have downloaded and installed agent on my local machine. How i can bypass proxy server from my local machine?

Comment: my local machine name is abc and my tfs server is server/tfs. agent is installed on my local machine, i have checked microsoft documentation for run private agent to bypass proxy it says, ./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 .... but it do not explain that proxyurl for my local machine i.e. http://localhost:8888 or my tfs url http://myserver/tfs.

Comment: also, my TFS is on different domain i.e. TFS\myusername and my machine is on different domain mymachine\mymachine.

Comment: when i am trying to execute ./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "1" --proxypassword "1" it says unrecognized command-line input --proxyurl, --proxyusername -- proxypassword

Comment: So after hammering my head into this many times, what i have identified is My Build Server is on Domain DEV and my TFS Server is on domain TFS_DOMAIN. agent is saving credentials for DEV domain. however, i have tried to configure it like, S E:\agent> ./config.cmd --unattended --url https://myTFS Server/tfs --auth Integrated --pool DemoAgent --a
gent DEV_MACHINE_NAME --windowslogonaccount TFS_DOMAIN\aqdas--windowslogonpassword pasword101

Comment: although domains are different but it is deploying build and running tests using assemblies type but not as test run.

Comment: @Aqdas What about other actions? build, deploy etc, do they work correctly? or have the same issue with the tests from test plans in the Test hub?

Comment: using build and deploy, if test run type is assemblies, it work fine, but if test tun type is test run, it dnt work, i am using on-premises TFS 2017

Comment: Did you exactly follow the steps to set up the envionment to [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub)

Comment: yes, i have followed same steps. but i have not created any testsettings file

Comment: @Aqdas I know you has been posted this more than a year ago but I'd like to ask you if were able to solve this issue, I'm facing the same, in Win Server 2012 R2. The  QFE is not available and changes the minBytesPerSecond didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: @FranciscoSevilla If your TFS is hosted in different domain, and the build server is on different domain then your TFS needs to be accessible on Server as well.  The solution to this is Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add your TFS port & url i.e. 127.0.0.1       localhostTFs.com. You are facing this issue because your server is rejecting request as it is not allowed to access your TFS URL. so any request which you are sending through TFS is being rejected by your server. Please allow your TFS in server machine's host file to make it able to receive requests from your TFS server

Comment: once you make sure that your hosts has access to TFS, use your TFS credentials to register the TFS agent using Domain\Username & password as I have mentioned above in my previous comments dated: Feb 26 '18 at 20:15 . For your convenience, I am posting answer to this post.